# How to filter tensor from queue based on some predicate in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

How can I filter data stored in a queue using a predicate function? For example, let's say we have a queue that stores tensors of features and labels and we just need those that meet the predicate. I tried the following implementation without success:

```
feature, label = queue.dequeue()
if (predicate(feature, label)):
    enqueue_op = another_queue.enqueue(feature, label)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is to dequeue a batch, run them through the predicate test, use [`tf.where`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops.html#where) to produce a dense vector of the ones that match the predicate, and use [`tf.gather`](http://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/array_ops.html#gather) to collect the results, and enqueue that batch.  If you want that to happen automatically, you can start a queue runner on the second queue - the easiest way to do that is to use `tf.train.batch`:

Example:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(np.array([5, 1, 9, 4, 7, 0], dtype=np.int32))

q = tf.FIFOQueue(6, dtypes=[tf.int32], shapes=[])
enqueue = q.enqueue_many([a])
dequeue = q.dequeue_many(6)
predmatch = tf.less(dequeue, [5])
selected_items = tf.reshape(tf.where(predmatch), [-1])
found = tf.gather(dequeue, selected_items)

secondqueue = tf.FIFOQueue(6, dtypes=[tf.int32], shapes=[])
enqueue2 = secondqueue.enqueue_many([found])
dequeue2 = secondqueue.dequeue_many(3) # XXX, hardcoded

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  sess.run(enqueue)  # Fill the first queue
  sess.run(enqueue2) # Filter, push into queue 2
  print sess.run(dequeue2) # Pop items off of queue2
```

The predicate produces a boolean vector;  the `tf.where` produces a dense vector of the indexes of the true values, and the `tf.gather` collects items from your original tensor based upon those indexes.

A lot of things are hardcoded in this example that you'd need to make not-hardcoded in reality, of course, but hopefully it shows the structure of what you're trying to do (create a filtering pipeline).  In practice, you'd want QueueRunners on there to keep things churning automatically.  Using `tf.train.batch` is very useful to handle that automatically -- see [Threading and Queues](http://www.tensorflow.org/how_tos/threading_and_queues/index.html) for more detail.

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar to this for SparseTensors? It [seems](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1950) gather doesn't work for them.

Comment: Hey - thanks ! it's still the most straigtforward way ? also the numpy import is not rally needed is it ?

Comment: I think so, but I'll check a bit more.  The numpy import is needed just for this example to run, because I created 'a' as a constant using numpy.