# Dropping/skipping records when loading data

Tags: tensorflow

I've discovered some erroneous data in my training set (mis-labeled examples) and while I've fixed the source, I'd  like to continue experimenting with the same dataset so I need to skip these records.

I'm using a TFRecordReader and loading with parse_single_example & shuffle_batch. Can I provide a filter somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a short reference to how to do it in the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#filtering-records-or-producing-multiple-examples-per-record) using `tf.train.shuffle_batch()` and `enqueue_many=True`. If you can determine if an example is mislabeled using graph operations, then you can filter the result like so (adapted from [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33904534/6478364)):

```
X, y = tf.parse_single_example(...)
is_correctly_labelled = correctly_labelled(X, y)
X = tf.expand_dims(X, 0)
y = tf.expand_dims(y, 0)
empty = tf.constant([], tf.int32)
X, y = tf.cond(is_correctly_labelled,
               lambda: [X, y],
               lambda: [tf.gather(X, empty), tf.gather(y, empty)])
Xs, ys = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [X, y], batch_size, capacity, min_after_dequeue,
    enqueue_many=True)
```

The `tf.gather` is just a way to get a zero-sized slice. In numpy it would just be `X[[], ...]`.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to work great. Can you explain how the expand_dims part works? To me it appears to add an extra 1-sized dimension but I can't quite understand how it's used.

Comment: The extra 1-sized dimension is used by `shuffle_batch()` with `enqueue_many=True`. The size of the first dimension is how many items to enqueue, so one if `is_correctly_labelled == True` otherwise zero. Does that make sense?

Comment: Hi, is 'is_correctly_labelled' a python bool variable? In this situation, it gives me an error: "TypeError: pred must not be a Python bool". Then if not, what type is the variable? How to get it? Thank you for your kind answer or advice.

Comment: @Kongsea: is_correctly_labelled must be computed from your graph. So for example, if you wanted to only keep examples where y was larger than 100, you could do:

is_correctly_labelled = y > 100

Comment: Yes, I finally know the reason and found it must be a bool tensor. Thank you.