# How to filter data points stored in feature map?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm using [TF.Learn estimator](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard3/tf.contrib.learn.Estimator.md#tfcontriblearnestimator__init__model_fnnone-model_dirnone-confignone-paramsnone-estimatorinit) to do prediction. The data to the [fit method](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard3/tf.contrib.learn.Estimator.md#tfcontriblearnestimatorfitxnone-ynone-input_fnnone-stepsnone-batch_sizenone-monitorsnone-max_stepsnone-estimatorfit) is passed as a input function that returns a feature map -- a python dictionary mapping feature names to the tensors dequeueing them from the disc:

```
def input_fn():
    feature_columns = get_feature_columns()
    features = tf.contrib.layers.create_feature_spec_for_parsing(feature_columns=feature_columns)
    feature_map = tf.contrib.learn.io.read_batch_features(
      file_pattern=data_dir,
      batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
      features=features)
    target = feature_map.pop("target")
    return feature_map, target
```

I would like to filter the data based on some predicate `P`, so that the estimator will get the points still batched in batches of BATCH_SIZE, but only those satisfying `P`. How can I easily achieve that?

(The question is similar to: [How to filter tensor from queue based on some predicate in tensorflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33903569/how-to-filter-tensor-from-queue-based-on-some-predicate-in-tensorflow), but there you filter only one tensor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a filtering queue and having a queuerunner which dequeues a single element from the result of read_batch_features and conditionally enqueues it on the filtering queue based on your predicate should work.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output of [read_batch_features](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/shard4/tf.contrib.learn.read_batch_features.md#tfcontriblearnread_batch_featuresfile_pattern-batch_size-features-reader-randomize_inputtrue-num_epochsnone-queue_capacity10000-feature_queue_capacity100-reader_num_threads1-parser_num_threads1-namenone-read_batch_features) is a dict, not a queue.

I tried to create a queue and enqueue `feature_map.values()`, but got type error (float32 vs SparseTensor).

Comment: I also tried evaluating the feature_map and enqueuing it into the queue, but still had the problems with the SparseTensors -- their contents is of type ndarray, but I can't specify that as a queue's dtype.

Comment: To enqueue a sparsetensor you need to serialize it.